# Excel AddIn How to change the Dialog title?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins, office-dialog-api

I am trying Excel Addin with dialog api, and I have such dialog below:

[image]

How can I change the content in green area?

How can I disable the close button in red area?

Answer (score 2):

1. The title is the name of your add-in specified in the manifest file. It is out of your control.
2. There is no way to remove the close button on the upper right corner of the dialog window.

Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

Comment: I'll add that Microsoft does have a work item to support modification of the dialog title. We hope that feature will be available sometime this year.

Comment: I can see  the title seems to be config in manifest with `DisplayName`, but, how to control the url like `https://localhost:3000/dialog.html`. For your link, I can see the [Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/images/auth-o-dialog-open.png), there is no url

Comment: You need to publish the add-in to any web server.